# CAAT - repeating behavior effect on event trigger

Tags: javascript, events, animation, 2d

Using CAAT I can bind an event to adding a behavior to an actor. However I cannot figure out how to repeat the behavior effect on consequent event trigger.
Here is the code:

```
circle.mouseDown = function(e){
    circle.emptyBehaviorList();
    circle.addBehavior(circle_jump);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4frL/1/

Clicking on the circle makes it jump once, then clicking again does nothing, although BehaviorList should be empty before adding the same behavior again.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to declare/apply the behaviour once, then when you need the actor (ball) to move you just have to say "when".
Basically you have to change your code to something like this:

```
circle.addBehavior(circle_jump);
scene.addChild(circle);

circle.mouseDown = function(e){
    circle_jump.setFrameTime(scene.time,2000);
}
```

setFrameTime( ) tells the actor when [scene.time -> now] and how long [2000 ms] the actor has to follow his behaviour.
I hope I've been clear enough.

ps. The ball now takes a jump at page load, that's because you have to comment this line:

```
    var circle_jump = new CAAT.PathBehavior().
                setPath(path_jump).
    /* THIS ONE setFrameTime(0,2000). */
                setCycle(false).
                setAutoRotate(false);
```